# How to configure Yoast to accept a URL to a remote image for the social image

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I'm running Yoast SEO plugin on my Wordpress site. I'm using the plugin mainly to be able to set the `og:image`, `og:title` and `og:description` for each page. By default, you can only set the "Social Image" by selecting (or uploading then selecting) an image from the media library:

[image]

I'd like to make a modification (via hooks/actions I would guess) such that in addition to the image selector, there is also a text field that will accept a URL and do the same thing with that image thta it does with the one selected with the picker (which is assign it as the value of `og:image`).

The plugin, Featured Image from URL (FIFU), does this very thing for a post's Featured Image, so I'm hoping that the same can be applied to Yoast. I've looked through their developer/support site and can't find a list of hooks or anything useful for this.

Anyone have any ideas?